# Remove decimal point in ScientificForm

Tags: plotting, ticks

I am trying to remove the decimal point displayed on the y-axis ticks. At the very least, a zero should follow the decimal point. I have included a MWE below.

```
Plot[Exp[x], {x, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> {-10^6, 10^6}, Frame -> True, 
Axes -> False, FrameLabel -> {Style["x",16],Style["f(x)",16]},
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black,16,Thickness[0.003]],
FrameTicks -> {{{{0,0}, {10^6,ScientificForm[10^6.0]},{10^6/2,ScientificForm[10^6.0/2]}},None},{Automatic,None}}]
```

This code generates the following figure. Does the problem stem from the use of `ScientificForm`?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe use `NumberPoint`

```
Plot[Exp[x], {x, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> {-10^6, 10^6}, Frame -> True, 
Axes -> False, FrameLabel -> {Style["x",16],Style["f(x)",16]},
FrameStyle -> Directive[Black,16,Thickness[0.003]],
FrameTicks -> {{{{0,0}, {10^6,ScientificForm[10^6.0,NumberPoint->""]}, 
{10^6/2,ScientificForm[10^6.0/2,NumberPoint->""]}},None},{Automatic,None}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A footnote to 1066's answer:

I suggest to use `Table` for better readability or if you want to add more y-ticks. And with `BaseStyle` you can shorten `FrameLabel`.

```
Plot[Exp[x], {x, -20, 20},
 BaseStyle -> 16,
 PlotRange -> {-10^6, 10^6},
 Frame -> True,
 Axes -> False,
 FrameLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"},
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.003]],
 FrameTicks -> {
   {Table[{x, ScientificForm[x, NumberPoint -> ""]}, {x, {0, 10.^6, 10.^6/2}}], None},
   {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]