# Specifying tick values and keeping minor ticks

Tags: plotting, ticks

I am unsure how to keep the minor ticks when I specify the tick values. For instance, consider the MWE

```
Plot[Sinh[x], {x, -20, 20}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Table[{x, 
      ScientificForm[x, NumberPoint -> ""]}, {x, {15.^5, 15.^5/2, 
       0, -15.^5/2, -15.^5}}], None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

which produces the plot

[image]

How can I keep the minor ticks on the left vertical axis?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you removing the number point? The resulting tick labels are quite misleading.

Comment: @MarcoB Apologies, I did not mean to do that here. I have done so for a previous problem (see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/291637/remove-decimal-point-in-scientificform)

Comment: The `{15.^5, 15.^5/2, 0, -15.^5/2, -15.^5}` should be `{15.*^5, 15.*^5/2, 0, -15.*^5/2, -15.*^5}` and remove the `, NumberPoint -> ""`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks, but this does not seem to keep the minor ticks on the vertical axis.

Comment: Yes, but it avoids the nonsensical labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Flavor to taste:

```
yTicks = Join[{#, "", {0.006, 0.}} & /@ Range[-10^6., 10^6., 10^5.],
   {#, ScientificForm[#], {0.01, 0.}} & /@
    {15.*^5, 15.*^5/2, 0, -15.*^5/2, -15.*^5}];

Plot[Sinh[x], {x, -20, 20},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks ->
  {{yTicks, None}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! May I ask what the Range[...] controls?

Comment: It specifies that the minor ticks (without labels) be placed at intervals of 10^5.